# Why is there no stop_using namespace directive

Tags: c++, namespaces

**Question:**
Is there a technical reason for why there isn't something like a `stop_using namespace` directive in c++?

Do you know if the committee has ever considered it?  Or is it just one of those features that no one found valuable enough to fight it through the standardization process?

With technical reason I mean something like "it is un-implementable / would play havoc with lookup rules / would make the compiler x-times slower / no one knows how this would interact with feature X ..."

**Background:**
There is a lot of discussion in the c++ community at large about when and if using `using namespace` is appropriate. My impression is that it could be a much more useful tool, if there was a way to localize its effect that does not require a local scope (as in inside of a function body). The reason I come up with this question at all, because it is imho a similar situation as with macros. Sometimes use of localized macros do make code more readable and especially make it easier to follow the dry-principle, but you generally don't want them to leak to other parts of the code, so you `#undef` them right after usage. It would be great to have the same ability for namespaces.

A concrete example, of what I mean is this:

```
// config.h
constexpr auto timeout1     = std::chrono::milliseconds{ 100 };
constexpr auto timeout2     = std::chrono::seconds{ 5 };
constexpr auto backoff_time = std::chrono::milliseconds{ 10 };
constexpr auto time_to_live = std::chrono::minutes{ 2 };
constexpr auto interval     = std::chrono::microseconds{ 300 };
```

would become

```
// config.h
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

constexpr auto timeout1     = 100ms;
constexpr auto timeout2     = 5s;
constexpr auto backoff_time = 10ms;
constexpr auto time_to_live = 2min;
constexpr auto interval     = 300us;

stop_using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

Which is imho much more readable.

Comment: I think the real question is: "Why is there a 'using' directive?" ;)

Comment: How about putting the variables in their own scope, for example a `namespace`? Then the `using` directive will pull the symbols into only *that* namespace.

Comment: @klutt: As I said, there is a lot of controversy about that feature and some prominent persons on the committee do consider it usefull, so I think it is a valid question, why it wasn't improved.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Because then you have to prepend that namespace to the name while the scope should be a pure implementation detail. Also it would have an effect on ADL

Comment: @MikeMB Yes, I was just mocking the keyword using a little bit. See my answer below. The solution is to put it in a scope.

Comment: i think that it would just further decrease readablity of. c++ code without real need in it. File-based limitation is sufficient and enforces folks to organize the code a bit. You can imagine **using** in one header file and **stop_using** in another. In my opinion, something like `using {...}` would be better.

Comment: @Serge: *"File-based limitation is sufficient"* Even if that where true (I don't think so and usually only use `using namespace` in function scope), the problem is that we currently don't have the possibility to limit the effects of `using namespace` to a single file - it is iether limited to a namespace/function scope or the remaining TU. Also, you can already have opening braces in one header file and closing braces in another (I hope no one actually does this). Anyway, a solution like `using {...}` would also be fine, but again, why doesn't it exist?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has ever been proposed.

I have seen people work around the limitation using the following technique:

```
// config.h

namespace config_detail
{

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

constexpr auto timeout1     = 100ms;
constexpr auto timeout2     = 5s;
constexpr auto backoff_time = 10ms;
constexpr auto time_to_live = 2min;
constexpr auto interval     = 300us;

}  // namespace config_detail

using config_detail::timeout1;
using config_detail::timeout2;
using config_detail::backoff_time;
using config_detail::time_to_live;
using config_detail::interval;
```

It isn't entirely satisfactory as it does involve repetition.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is a viable technique if e.g. one has a decent amount of code and in the end only needs to publish a single class. But in cases like this, it somewhat defeats the purpose of using  `using namespace` in the first place, because you end up writing even more boilder-plate code not less (whether readability is still improved depends imho on the reader).

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for what you want is simply `{   }`. For your example:

```
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  constexpr auto timeout1     = 100ms;
  constexpr auto timeout2     = 5s;
  constexpr auto backoff_time = 10ms;
  constexpr auto time_to_live = 2min;
  constexpr auto interval     = 300us;
} // stop_using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

Comment: I don't think scoping like this is possible in global/namespace scope - is it?

Comment: Nope - it isn't

Comment: did you try it or at least google it? see for example http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/ (scroll down for an example) , "_using and using namespace have validity only in the same block in which they are stated or in the entire source code file if they are used directly in the global scope._"

Comment: [I did](https://godbolt.org/g/VBCjoc) - with multiple different compilers. Did you?

Comment: I didn't, I don't have access to a compiler until tonight. Point taken. I trusted my memory and that website.

Comment: If you have access to it (not blocked by a firewall or such), then the compiler explorer website (https://gcc.godbolt.org/) is a great and simple tool to verify small code snippets.